# Clarifying maps in algebraic number theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $K$ be a quadratic imaginary number field. I wonder why, something which seems to be standard (yet by no means clear for me) is a natural map:

> $$\mathbf{Z}/\mathfrak{m} \cap \mathbf{Z} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}$$

Do we know explicitly what this map is? I am more precisely interested in determining whether or not a given element is in the image, but I feel totally lost. It is often mentionned the following exact sequence:

> $$1 \to \mathbf{C}^\times \times \hat{\mathcal{O}}^\times \to \mathbf{A}(K)^\times/K^\times \to Cl(K) \to 1$$

But I do not see the relation... Do someone has any idea or source? It will be of great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a general fact about modules over commutative rings. Note that $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}$ is a $\Bbb Z/\mathfrak{m}\cap\Bbb Z$ module--the action is just multiply by $n\in\Bbb Z$, and clearly it is trivial on $\mathfrak{m}\cap\Bbb Z$, so you can map the latter in the former by looking at $\Bbb Z/\mathfrak{m}\cap\Bbb Z\cdot 1$, as a cyclic $\Bbb Z/\mathfrak{m}\cap\Bbb Z$ submodule of $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't understood that. But I remain not grasping what is the image exactly. I got prime-to-$\mathfrak{m}$ ideals of the form $\varpi_\mathfrak{p}^e$ (with $\varpi$ and uniformizer), and I am really lost when I wonder if I can know if they are in the image or not... do we know an explicit/computable/reachable form for the elements in the image ?

Comment: @Wolker see my edit, it's simpler to observe the image as a cyclic $\Bbb Z/\mathfrak{m}\cap\Bbb Z$ module.

Comment: @AdamHugues Ok I will try it, thank you for the help and enlightening formulation ;)

Comment: @Wolker my pleasure. Cheers!

Comment: @AdamHugues It enligthened me a lot, but I begin to understand where I get lost each time : the elements I am trying to determine to be or not in this image are of the form $\varpi_\mathfrak{p}^e$ or product of those... but aren't they ideles ? How can I view them as classes of integers ? Maybe something relying on the same kind of identifications, for instance $\hat{O}^\times/(1+\mathfrak{m}\hat{O}^\times) \cong O_K/\mathfrak{m}$ ?

Comment: @Wolker $\Bbb Z$ acts on $\mathcal{O}_K$ by multiplication by $n$, in particular $\Bbb Z\subseteq\mathcal{O}_K$ so you just map the integers to themselves modulo $\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: @AdamHugues Yes but some of those elements seems to be in the image, while other not, so it has to be a way to consider the $\varpi_\mathfrak{p}^e$ as elements of $O_K/\mathfrak{m}$, isn't it ?

Comment: @Wolker no, the map isn't necessarily surjective (it's probably not in fact!) Take the case where $\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal, then $\mathfrak{p}\cap\Bbb Z=(p)$ is a prime ideal of $\Bbb Z$, and $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$ is the residue field. If there is any inertia, this is a proper extension of $\Bbb Z/(p)$, so the map has no hope of hitting everything.

Comment: @AdamHugues In this last case for instance, if I take a uniformizer for $\mathfrak{p}$, then could we day that $\mathfrak{p}$ lies in the image ? And the other $\mathfrak{p}^n$ ? (Thanks to you I begin to understand, but it seems to be a lot of hidden little arguments like what you are explaining... all the time)

Comment: @Wolker no, this is a simple ring map, I think you are expecting a lot more things to show up than actually do. The map is very basic from the very beginnings of the topic, uniformizers do not play a part in this particular map. I know you see them a lot in discussions of adeles, but I'm only addressing the question of the natural map from $\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z\cap\mathfrak{m}\to \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}$ which is very, **very** basic. The things that are in the image are things in $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}$ hit by integers under the map from $\mathcal{O}_K\to\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}$. (contd)

Comment: In particular, we can say nothing about what else is in there with just the information we have, it's not a very deep fact at all, that is why no one ever explains it in the books.

Comment: @AdamHugues Ok, so I think I haven't read sufficiently well the whole thing to explain it here after your first answers: I take an idèle $x=\prod_i \varpi_{\mathfrak{p}_i}^{e_i} \in \mathbb{A}_K/K^\times$. And the question is: when is this element $x$, taken modulo $\mathfrak{m}$ (so now it lies in $O_K/\mathfrak{m}$, right ?), in the image of the application above?

Comment: @ AdamHughes in general We have $R$ a subring of $A$ and $I$ an ideal $\subset A$, how do we find the generators of $A/I$ and $R/(R \cap I)$ and the mentioned inclusion map ? cc @Wolker

Comment: @wolker exactly when there is an integer in it's inverse image

Comment: @user1952009 just take images of generators of $R$ or $A$.

Comment: Also @wolker, you perhaps are asking two different questions now: the map from $\Bbb Z / \Bbb Z\cap\mathfrak{m}\to\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}$ is one thing and is purely a fact about rings, nothing about the adeles or ideles matters for this map. If you are **also** interested in the other map you mention you might get a more thorough answer on the follow up by posting a new question on it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd think of it like this.

There is a natural embedding $\mathbb Z\hookrightarrow\mathcal O_K$, and hence a projection
$$\mathbb Z\hookrightarrow\mathcal O_K\to\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak m.$$

The kernel of this map is exactly the elements of $\mathfrak m$ which are also in $\mathbb Z$ - i.e. $\mathbb Z\cap\mathfrak m$. We deduce that there is an injection
$$\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z\cap \mathfrak m\hookrightarrow\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak m.$$

In the case where $K$ is an imaginary quadratic number field, these two fields are just the residue fields of $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathcal O_K$ with respect to $\mathbb Z\cap \mathfrak m$ and $\mathfrak m$ respectively. Therefore, the map will be surjective if and only if the two residue fields are equal, which happens if and only if $\mathbb Z\cap\mathfrak m$ ramifies or splits in $K$.

Comment: It's not going to be a field unless $\mathfrak{m}$ is prime. Also I would avoid "hence a projection," the projection exists regardless of any inclusion. And you mean the kernel of the map restricted to the subring $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I assumed $\mathfrak m$ referred to a maximal ideal, but I think my meaning in the last paragraph is clear enough. I think it's reasonably clear too that "this map" refers to the composite map $\mathbb Z\to\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak m$.